Property not passed correctly onto sub component
I have a simple site which loads property-related data from a Danish national data provider, SDFI. I have simplified the code based on your feedback and destructured the props component.
I am having issues passing down the right values from a mother component to a sub component.
My code looks like this:
My main component:
Search.js:
  import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
  import { useState } from "react"; 
  import { AsyncTypeahead } from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";
  import ResultsDisplay from './ResultsDisplay';
  const SEARCH_URI = "https://api.dataforsyningen.dk/autocomplete";

  const AsyncSearch = () => {
      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
      const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
      const [found, setFound] = useState(false);
      const [hest, setHest] = useState([])
      
      const handleSearch = async (query) => {
          setIsLoading(true);    
          const response = await fetch(`${SEARCH_URI}?q=${query}&type=adresse`);
          const addresses = await response.json();

          setOptions(addresses);
          console.log(addresses);
          setIsLoading(false);
      };

      const handleChange = async (selected) => { 
        if (selected === undefined || selected.length == 0 )
        return;
      
        const s = selected[0] 
        const aga = s.data.adgangsadresseid;
        let res;
        if (s.data.adgangsadresseid === undefined)
        {
          res = await fetch(`/bolig/${selected[0].data.id}`);  
        } else { 
          res = await fetch(`/bolig/${selected[0].data.adgangsadresseid}`);
        } 
        let searchResults = await res.json();
        console.log(`seachresults: ${searchResults}`)
        setHest(searchResults); 
        setFound(true);
      }
    // Bypass client- side filtering by returning `true`. Results are already
    // filtered by the search endpoint, so no to do>it again.
    const filterBy = () => true; 

    return (
      <>      
        <AsyncTypeahead
          filterBy={filterBy}
          id="async-load"
          isLoading={isLoading}
          labelKey="forslagstekst"
          onChange={handleChange}
          minLength={3}
          onSearch={handleSearch}
          options={options}
          placeholder="Indtast adresse"
          renderMenuItemChildren={(opt) => (
            <>
              <span>{opt.tekst}</span>
            </>
          )}
          />     
          <ResultsDisplay hest={hest} />
        
      </>

      );
  }

  export default AsyncSearch;

Child component (ResultsDisplay.js)


import { useState } from "react"
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'; 

const ResultsDisplay = ({hest}) => { 
    
    console.log("LOL");
    return(
        <>
            <Container>
                <h2>Grund</h2>
                <p>{hest.grund.grundareal}</p>
            </Container>
            {hest.bygninger.map((h, i) => {
                return (
                <Container>
                    <h2>Bygning</h2>
                    <p>Opfoerelsesaar: {h.byg026Opførelsesår}</p>
                    <p>Antal etager: {h.byg054AntalEtager}</p>
                    <p>Bygningens anvendelse: {h.byg021BygningensAnvendelse}</p>
                    <p>Varmeinstallation: {h.byg056Varmeinstallation}</p>
                    <p>Samlede boligareal: {h.byg039BygningensSamledeBoligAreal}</p>
                    <p>Bebygget areal: {h.byg041BebyggetAreal}</p>
                    <p>Kommunekode: {h.kommunekode}</p>
                    <p>Jordstykke: {h.jordstykke}</p>
                    <p>Grund: {h.grund}</p>
                </Container>);
            })}
        </>
    );
}      

export default ResultsDisplay;```

In the above example, the value of "hest" is never passed correctly from AsyncSearch to ResultsDisplay. If I debug the value of grund.grundareal inside AsyncSearch the value is correct (i.e. it's an object with the property grundareal = some integer). However, after passing "grund" to ResultsDisplay, it shows up simply as an empty object.
What am I doing wrong? Could this be related to how the "hest" object is passed over to ResultsDisplay?


hi you are required to do this, if you want to get the values destructured
({hest, grund}). This should work

There might be an issue that you are not getting the values right as expected.
You should try the following ({hest, grund}) instead of (hest, grund)
As you are already DE-structuring the parameters, this approach should work.
More info

The first argument doesn't need to be an object.

I think the first time "hest" is an empty array. When the component first renders, "hest" is empty. Then, when you call "handleChange" and update "hest" with "setHest(searchResults)", it changes. You should update your code like this. I suggest two ways, which one to choose.
1st: hest && hest.length > 0 && && <ResultsDisplay hest={hest} />
 
2nd: <ResultsDisplay hest={hest} />
  const ResultsDisplay = ({ hest }) => {
  if (!hest || hest.length === 0) {
    return <Container>No results found</Container>;
  }
  return (
  //inside JSX
  )
 }


If first argument does needed to be an object then what it would be?

@syedbilalHaider i guess you need to read the question clearly. The question clearly mentions that he needs to de-structure the object. and you want it to be a single prop.
